# Saving array of strings using NSUserDefaults into another UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsuserdefaults

I've two `UITableView` with custom cell, the first `UITableView` has array of string in `UILabel` and `UIButton`.

This is my FirstViewController(first `UITableView`)

[image]

And the secondViewController( second `UITableView`) has only `UILabel`.

What I'm trying to do is to click for example at the second cell `UIButton` "add to second table" and pass it in an array using `NSUserDefaults` into the secondViewController, and when i click at the first cell `UIButton` "add to second table" it should keep the first value and append this value with it and add it to the secondViewController.

This is my code (in firstViewController) but as you can see here I'm sending the whole array every time, is it possible to send each time String and append it together in an array in `NSUserDefaults` and then retrieve it in the second `UITableView`:

```
func add(sender:AnyObject){
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array, forKey: "Array")
    }
```

i tried to send it this way but its only sending one String not an Array of Strings :

```
func add(sender:AnyObject){
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array[sender.tag], forKey: "Array")
    }
```

Code in the secondViewController :

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Array") != nil){
    array  =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Array")! as! NSArray
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code with following code:

```
func add(sender:AnyObject){
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Array") != nil){
    array1  =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Array")! as! NSArray
}
 array1.append(array[sender.tag])
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array1, forKey: "Array")
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Code in the secondViewController :

```
  if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("Array") != nil){
        array  =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Array")! as! NSArray
    }
}
```

Comment: This is passing the whole array, I'm saying i need to pass Strings and append them in array. like array[indexPath.row]

Comment: its only appending one value, when i click on add to fav for second and third value, i have only one value in the second table !! also its forcing me to cast it to String like :             `array.append(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Array")! as! NSString as String)`

Comment: array1 is of type what ?

Comment: is it possible to check if the item that is being added exist already in NSUserdefaults array before adding it ?